# Google OAuth Login Solutions?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

Can anyone recommend a Google OAuth solution for D8?

I've done some looking, the only real viable solution that I can find is the [OneAll Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_login) module. This would potentially work for us, but we don't necessarily need something with 35+ login options. There seem to be other modules out there, but either seem to be confined to D6/D7 or have very low usage stats.

I'll explain what we are attempting to do. We have a dashboard that our customers login to, they can then launch into their various services from there. We'd just like to provide the option to login & associate a Google account with your existing D8 account to streamline the process.

EDIT: @drastik provided links to the [Social API Stack](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_google) module and it works without any issue. This is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: How about the openid_connect module?

Comment: Thanks @MarioSteinitz but we ended up using the Social API module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Social API stack is the solution going forward in D8:
https://www.drupal.org/project/social_api
https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth
https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_google

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not sure how I didn't come across this upon my searching. This worked perfectly for us.